# Fast moving stars at equal distance in straight line 18.04.2020 evening

Tags: star, amateur-observing

Yesterday, I have observed fast moving bright stars at equal distance in straight line (18 March 2020) in Germany around 20:00 in night. I was facing the east direction. What could be the reason for these symetrical moving stars?